# Accessing layout template through layout_id

Tags: boto, mechanicalturk

I use `boto` to create mturk HITs with a layout I defined in the project editor.

Now I noticed that every time I edit a project's layout template the `Layout ID` changes. Is there are any way to access the old/*overwritten* layout using the website, `boto` or a command line interface?

The reason why I want to do this is, that I noticed errors in my HITs and I want to check if the reason is a error in the template or wrongly inputed data. But I edited the project in the mean time so I am not 100% sure how the layout template looked.

Comment: I don't think there's anyway to access this. In fact, I hadn't noticed this behavior before, but I suppose it makes sense at some level.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Thomas.